# Undefined Variable :def__init__(self)

Tags: python-3.8

I am unable to declare a constructor in Python 3.8. I am not able to declare a constructor. The system is showing the error message:

```
"Undefined Variable" and "illegal target for annotations.
```

```py
class Employee:
    def__init__(self,name,id):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
    def dispaly(self):
        print("ID: %d\nName: %s"%(self.id,self.name))

emp1 = Employee("Robert",101)
emp1.dispaly()
```

Comment: You are missing a space between *def* and *__init__*. `def __init__(self):`. Also please add code as text in your question instead of an image.

Comment: Please paste your code here as text, not as a screenshot

Comment: I was not giving a space, that was the problem. Thanks to stud3nt. The entire code is working fine now.The code is as follows:-   class Employee:
    def __init__(self,name,id):
      self.name = name  
      self.id = id

    def dispaly(self):
        print("ID: %d\nName: %s"%(self.id,self.name))


emp1 = Employee("Robert",101)
emp1.dispaly()

Comment: @stud3nt Just a head's up, next time you edit a post to add something that was came from a comment, please state that it was in a comment from the OP in your edit summary. We can't actually see comments from the Review Queue when we're looking at suggested edits. One reviewer had voted to reject your edit, probably because it wasn't clear the code was from the OP and not an attempt to create it from the screenshot.

Comment: @BSMP Sure, will take care of it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a space between `def` and `__init__` keywords.

 Correct way:

```py
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, name, id):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id

    def display(self):
        print("Employee Name is {} and ID is {}.".format(self.name, self.id))

emp1 = Employee("Robert", "E001")
emp1.display()
```